# My navbar-logo component shifts when I resize the browser window window

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, responsive-design, jsx

I have a **logo** that shifts whenever I make the browser **window smaller**. I'm not sure what is causing this I have attached my `jsx` and `css` code below. I tried to change **width values** but it shifts regardless of its properties. I can't provide images right now because stack overflow won't let me but I can try to DM them if needed or something. Thank you!

jsx code

```
  return (
    <>
      <nav className="navbar">
        <div className="navbar-container container">
          <Link className="navbar-logo" onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
            <img className='navbar-icon'
              src={Icon} alt='icon'
              width='auto'
              height='60px'
              position='flex' />
            SKYPRECISION
          </Link>
          <div className="menu-icon" onClick={handleClick}>
            {click ? <FaTimes /> : <FaBars />}
          </div>
          <ul className={click ? 'nav-menu active' : 'nav-menu'}>
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link to='/' className='nav-links' onClick={closeMobileMenu}>
                  Home
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link
                  to='/services'
                  className='nav-links'
                  onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                >
                  About
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className='nav-item'>
                <Link
                  to='/products'
                  className='nav-links'
                  onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                >
                  Team
                </Link>
              </li>
              <li className='nav-btn'>
                {button ? (
                  <Link to='/sign-up' className='btn-link'>
                    <Button buttonStyle='btn-outline'>LOG-IN</Button>
                  </Link>
                ) : (
                  <Link to='/sign-up' className='btn-link'>
                    <Button
                      buttonStyle='btn-outline'
                      buttonSize='btn-mobile'
                      onClick={closeMobileMenu}
                    >
                      LOG-IN
                    </Button>
                  </Link>
                )}
              </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </nav>
    </>
  )
```

css code

```
/* Colors
    #009444 - light green
    #006838 - dark green
    #46639f - purple
*/

.navbar {
  background: #46639f;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1.2rem;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 999;
}

.navbar-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 80px;
}

.container {
  z-index: 1;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-left: auto;
  padding-right: 50px;
  padding-left: 50px;
}

.navbar-logo {
  color: #009444;
  justify-self: start;
  cursor: pointer;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 2rem;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  position: auto;
  object-fit: contain;
}

.navbar-icon {
  margin-right: 0.5rem;
}

.nav-menu {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  list-style: none;
  text-align: center;
  justify-content: end;
}

.nav-item {
  height: 80px;
  border-bottom: 2px solid transparent;
}

.nav-item:hover {
  border-bottom: 3px solid #009444;
}

.nav-links {
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  padding: 0.5rem 1rem;
  height: 100%;
}

.fa-bars {
  color: #fff;
}

.menu-icon {
  display: none;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .NavbarItems {
    position: relative;
  }

  .nav-menu {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    width: 100%;
    height: 90vh;
    position: absolute;
    top: 80px;
    left: -100%;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
  }

  .nav-menu.active {
    background: #1c2237;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 1;
    transition: all 0.6s ease;
    z-index: 1;
  }

  .nav-links {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2rem;
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
  }

  .nav-links:hover {
    color: #f00946;
    transform: scale(1.2);
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
  }

  .nav-item:hover {
    border: none;
  }

  .nav-item {
    width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar-logo {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    transform: translate(25%, 50%);
  }

  .menu-icon {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
  }

  .fa-times {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 2rem;
  }

  .nav-btn {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 120px;
  }
}
```

Comment: Feel free to send me a dm, or post a link to an example on jsfiddle or codepen. I'd be happy to help.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. Since stackoverflow is the perfect antisocial social network heres the github repo Im using https://github.com/varghedj/skyprecisionWebsite

Comment: So I looked at your repo. Is everything pushed up? The code in the repo doesn't match the code that you're got here.

Comment: i just pushed everything it should be good now

Answer (score 0):

I pulled down your repo and worked through the issue. The problem was caused by absolute positioning and using transforms. While those are both fine, they take the item out of the flow of the document. When you take them out of the flow of the DOM. That's what was causing the shift.

Here is the CSS you need to fix the issue. This isn't all of the CSS, it's just what needs to be changed.

```css
.navbar {
    align-items: center;
    background: #46639f;
    height: 80px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}
.container {
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-right: 50px;
    padding-left: 50px;
    width: 100%;
}
.navbar-container {
    align-items: center;
    display: flex;
    height: 80px;
    justify-content: space-between;
}
.navbar-logo {
    align-items: center;
    color: #009444;
    display: flex;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.navbar-icon {
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
    object-fit: contain;
    width: auto;
    height: 60px;
}


/* The styles for .navbar-logo in the media query are unneeded. Please remove them. */
@media screen and (max-width: 1300px) {
  .menu-icon {
    cursor: pointer;
    display: block;
    height: 1.8rem;
    width: 1.8rem;
  }
}
```

Additionally, the height and width values for your SVG logo should be changed from `1em` to `100%`.

Comment: Thanks! I can't upvote but I appreciate the help

Comment: @varghedj You may not be able to upvote but you can select the correct answer.

Comment: i did click the button just letting you know because it wont show 

Comment: @varghedj what about the check? Can you click that?

Answer (score -1):

fit : contain to the .navbar_logo class.This reshapes the logo everytime you make the window smaller. Let me know how it goes

Comment: can u send a screen shot of the problem??

Comment: I can't sent pictures yet because I dont have enough stackoverflow renown (or whatever they call it)